# Create vector of all classes implementing an interface

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface "Vehicle" and classes implementing that interface Car, Bicycle, Bike etc.

Can I create a Vector of the interface and assign it instances of the implementing classes?
For ex:

```
Vector<Vehicle> vi;
vi.add(0, new Car());
vi.add(1, new Bicycle());
```

etc.

So at runtime, I can simply check the index and invoke the required function?

Comment: Please suggest other better ways to do this as well.

Comment: Have you tried implementing your solution?

Comment: I tried implementing it this way:


   Vector<Vehicle> vi = new Vector<Vehicle>();
   vi.add(0, new Bike());

But, eclipse is throwing following error :

Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
  construct(s)
 - Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
 - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Comment: Use an `ArrayList`, a `Vector` is a legacy class with weird, mostly useless synchronisation semantics added.

Comment: @user1071840 And did that work? If not, what was the problem?

Comment: OOPS!! I got my error..sorry to bother you guys.. VERY silly mistake..please excuse me.. (I was writing code, outside method). Not in habit of coding in java..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can. It's a classical example of a polymorphism usage in runtime.

```
import java.util.Vector;

interface Vehicle {
    public int getNumberOfWheels();
}

class Car implements Vehicle {

    final int numberOfWheels = 4;

    public int getNumberOfWheels() {
        return numberOfWheels;
    }
}

class Bicycle implements Vehicle {

    final int numberOfWheels = 2;

    public int getNumberOfWheels() {
        return numberOfWheels;
    }
}

public class Program {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vector<Vehicle> vi = new Vector<Vehicle>();
        vi.add(0, new Car());
        vi.add(1, new Bicycle());
        for(Vehicle v: vi) {
            System.out.println(v.getClass().getName() 
                + " has " + v.getNumberOfWheels() + " wheels");
        }
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://compilr.com/evgeniynaydenov/polymorphism/Program.java)**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Interfaces are meant to be used that way.

Now for suggesting better ways to do that: very difficult to do, as it is not very clear what you need to do exactly. The first suggestion would be to use ArrayList instead of Vector. The main difference between the two is that Vector is "synchronized", which means thread safe. However, synchronization has a big impact on performance, and the Vector class achieve full thread safety by synchronizing access to ALL its methods. It is generally better to use non-synchronized containers and, if you need thread safety, to manage your own synchronization outside the container, as you can put them only where you need them depending on your usage.

In the extreme case where your list has a fixed size known in advance, you can even use a simple array, i.e.:

```
Vehicle[] vi = new Vehicle[2];
vi[0] = new Car();
vi[1] = new Bicycle();
```